# C++ creating and display values of smart pointers arrays

Tags: arrays, c++11, smart-pointers

Why can't I see output value of `smartPtr2D` from this code?

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<int[3]>[5]> smartPtr2D;
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        smartPtr2D[i][j] = 11;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << "value:" << smartPtr2D[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` behaves like a pointer and it doesn't point to anything, so dereferencing it will be undefined behavior. You need something like `smartPtr2D = std::make_shared<shared_ptr<int[3]>>();` and then you need to allocate memory for the inner `shared_ptr`s too.

Comment: You should consider using a wrapper around a flat array instead of combining pointers like that.

Comment: @nwp can you please, write some simple sample with smart pointers 2d array.

Comment: I did above in the comment. You just have to do it again for the other pointers.

Comment: Also note that this isn't what people normally think of as a 2d array. 2d arrays are thought of as contiguous. Your structure is more like an array of pointers to arrays, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: Thank You very much, because I see now that I don't have basic understanding of smart pointers. It looks like different to code writing before modern Cpp.

Comment: Consider [getting a book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3484570). [The tour](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html) is intended for people who know programming and some older C++ and just need to be brought up to speed with the modern part.